# array_search not working (returns null)

Tags: php, cakephp, null

I'm using CakePHP

I have $needle and $numbers:

```
$needle = 14;

$numbers =
Array
(
    [0] => 14 
    [1] => 15 
    [2] => 16 
)
```

I'm just doing this:

```
$n = array_search($needle,$numbers);
```

and $n returns NULL.

If you want full context here all the code, it's a php from an ajax call:

```
if(isset($_POST['numbers']))
        {
            $jobsX = $this->Job->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Job.owner' => $id)));

            $numbers = $_POST['numbers'];

            $n = 0;

            $this->autoRender = false;

            foreach($jobsX as $key => $jo)
            {       
                $needle = $jo['Job']['id'];

                $n = array_search($needle,$numbers);

                $jobsX[$key]['Job']['order'] = $n;
            }

            $this->Job->saveAll($jobsX);

            echo 1;
        }
```

Makes no sense to me...

EDIT:
IT WORKS if you do it outside the foreach... but why?

Comment: Are you **certain** `$numbers` is an `array`? I am doubtful.

Comment: If so what's the point? I even created a personalized function that compares a value with each element of the array and even so the result is the same... I mean... it returns that 16 is not the same as 16!

Comment: The *point*? Well... `array_search()` expects the second parameter to be an array. So if you aren't passing an array, it will not work as expected.

Comment: It works if I use it outside the foreach, and supplying the same arguments, except $needle, I put a number....

Comment: Solved... but the solution makes no sense to me:
use intval

$needle = intval($jo['Job']['id']);

Comment: Debug `$number` inside the loop. I'm sure it will make more sense then.

Comment: Yep, did that, what you see on the topic is from a debug inside the foreach

Comment: You should be debugging `$needle` because that variable change it value inside the for loop. I guess that you are gettinf the id as a string value, and what you did to fix that was a cast to int

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use intval:

```
$needle = intval($jo['Job']['id']);
```

I don't understand, this was not neccesary in another case...

Comment: $needle is null.